# Android Navigationdrawer toggle hamburger icon

Tags: android, actionbardrawertoggle

I am using  `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` as package for ActionBarToggle and it has the constructor as

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close)
```

How can I set the hamburger icon for toggle?

Answer (score 0):

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.yourIcon,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    )
```

Comment: This constructor is not supporting for android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.

Comment: The above constructor is  for android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle,

Comment: you can always change the hamburger icon from the OnCreate of the activity containig the drawer by using actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.newIcon);